# Turtle Python 3, Create a "mosaic tile" with a user supplied number of rows and columns and each with a turtle stamped in the middle of it

Tags: python, function, turtle-graphics

I need to create code, using specific functions, that creates rectangles in the user-supplies amount of rows and columns.

What I am trying to do is have the first rectangle start in the upper left corner and then it fills out the rest of rectangles for the specified rows and columns. Then it stamps in the center of each rectangle the turtle.

So far my code draws the first rectangle and then it just draws really long lines for the rest of them and then the turtle appears.

I currently have this:

```
import turtle
import random


# -----------------------------------------+
# draw_tile                                |
# -----------------------------------------+
# rectangle: the name of the turtle        |
# width: width of tile                     |
# height: height of tile                   |
# color: color of the tile                 |
# -----------------------------------------+
# Draw a rectangle with specfied fill      |
# color and black border. Call another     |
# function to stamp the tile.              |    
# -----------------------------------------+

rows = int(input("Enter number of rows: "))
columns = int(input("Enter number of columns: "))

def pick_color():
    colors = ["blue", "green", "yellow", "orange", "brown", "red", "pink", 
"turquoise"]
    random.shuffle(colors)
    return colors[0]



def draw_tile(rectangle, width, height):
    rectangle = turtle.Turtle()
    rectangle.fillcolor(pick_color())
    rectangle.begin_fill()
    rectangle.penup()
    rectangle.goto(-345,175)
    rectangle.pendown()
    for i in range(4):
        rectangle.forward(width)
        rectangle.left(90)
        rectangle.forward(height)
    for i in range(rows):
        rectangle.forward(width + width*i)

    rectangle.end_fill()

# -----------------------------------------+
# stamp_tile                               |
# -----------------------------------------+
# stamper: the name of the turtle          |
# w: width of the tile                     |
# h: height of the tile                    |
# -----------------------------------------+
# Stamp a black arrow in the center of     |
# the tile, pointing up.                   |
# -----------------------------------------+

def stamp_tile(stamper, w,h):
    stamper = turtle.Turtle()
    stamper.shape('turtle')
    stamper.color('green')
    stamper.stamp()
    stamper.penup()
    stamper.goto(-330,200)
    stamper.pendown()
    stamper.left(90)





# -----------------------------------------+
# main                                     |
# -----------------------------------------+
# This function has no parameters.         |
# -----------------------------------------+
# This function should  prompt the user    |
# for number of rows and columns, then     |
# draw a mosaic of randomly colored tiles. |
# Call the other two functions as needed.  |
# -----------------------------------------+
def main():

    t = turtle.Turtle()
    window = turtle.Screen()
    t.speed(0)
    draw_tile(t,200,50)
    stamp_tile(t,200,50)


    t.hideturtle()

# Call the main function to begin executing
main()
```

and I need it to look like this:

[What I need my code to create for the "mosaic tiles"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTB1L.png)

I appreciate anyone who answers this and can help me out!

Comment: What is your question?  It looks like you've barely begun to solve this problem.

Comment: I just need help figuring out how to have multiple rectangles (of the same shape) be created when a user enters a certain number or rows and columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just need help figuring out how to have multiple rectangles

Great, let's first clean up your code that draws a single tile:

```
def draw_tile(rectangle, width, height):
    rectangle = turtle.Turtle()
```

We don't need to create a new turtle as one is being passed in under the name `rectangle`.

```
    rectangle.fillcolor(pick_color())
    rectangle.begin_fill()
```

Based on your own documentation, `color` is passed in as the final argument, so we'll add that and move the call to `pick_color()` elsewhere.

```
    rectangle.penup()
    rectangle.goto(-345,175)
    rectangle.pendown()
```

Since we're going to draw multiple tiles with this routine, it makes no sense to tie it to a specific location like `(-345, 175)`, so we'll toss this.

```
    for i in range(4):
        rectangle.forward(width)
        rectangle.left(90)
        rectangle.forward(height)
```

This code is broken, it should repeat twice, not four times, since it draws two sides per iteration. And it should include an additional 90 degree left turn at the end.  We'll fix this.

```
    for i in range(rows):
        rectangle.forward(width + width*i)
```

This code does nothing as far as drawing the tile, so we'll toss it.

```
    rectangle.end_fill()
```

Here's the revised `draw_tile()`:

```
def draw_tile(rectangle, width, height, color):
    rectangle.pendown()
    rectangle.fillcolor(color)
    rectangle.begin_fill()

    for i in range(2):
        rectangle.forward(width)
        rectangle.left(90)
        rectangle.forward(height)
        rectangle.left(90)

    rectangle.end_fill()
    rectangle.penup()
```

The user has provided `rows` and `columns` and we need to stack tiles accordingly.  What we can use is a nested loop:

```
for row in range(rows):
    for column in range(columns):
```

We can't simply `t.goto(row, column)` as that ignores the dimensions of the tile, so we need to do something like:

```
        t.goto(column * 200, row * 100)
```

Which should work.  However, it won't be centered on the screen.  That's a more complicated calculation:

```
         t.goto(column * 200 - (columns * 100), row * 100 - (rows * 50))
```

We could easily break this code statement up and do some parts of it sooner.  But I leave that as an exercise for the programmer.  Let's put it all together:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import choice

COLORS = ["blue", "green", "yellow", "orange", "brown", "red", "pink", "turquoise"]

# -----------------------------------------+
# draw_tile                                |
# -----------------------------------------+
# rectangle: the name of the turtle        |
# width: width of tile                     |
# height: height of tile                   |
# color: color of the tile                 |
# -----------------------------------------+
# Draw a rectangle with specfied fill      |
# color and black border. Call another     |
# function to stamp the tile.              |
# -----------------------------------------+

def draw_tile(rectangle, width, height, color):
    rectangle.pendown()
    rectangle.fillcolor(color)
    rectangle.begin_fill()

    for i in range(2):
        rectangle.forward(width)
        rectangle.left(90)
        rectangle.forward(height)
        rectangle.left(90)

    rectangle.end_fill()
    rectangle.penup()

def pick_color():
    return choice(COLORS)

# -----------------------------------------+
# main                                     |
# -----------------------------------------+
# This function has no parameters.         |
# -----------------------------------------+
# This function should  prompt the user    |
# for number of rows and columns, then     |
# draw a mosaic of randomly colored tiles. |
# Call the other two functions as needed.  |
# -----------------------------------------+

def main():

    rows = int(input("Enter number of rows: "))
    columns = int(input("Enter number of columns: "))

    window = Screen()

    t = Turtle()
    t.speed('fastest')
    t.penup()

    for row in range(rows):
        for column in range(columns):
            t.goto(column * 200 - (columns * 100), row * 100 - (rows * 50))
            draw_tile(t, 200, 100, pick_color())

    t.hideturtle()
    window.exitonclick()

# Call the main function to begin executing
main()
```

Now you need to work out how to stamp onto each tile.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did have to change a couple of things to truly match the assignment. But you are a literal life saver!